# How to solve "Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 200 with 400" In gin

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine, go-gin, go-http

I'm trying to calculate a report independently of an HTTP request using the Gin framework, but I also want to return it to the request if it hasn't been closed yet. The following code snippet sometimes works correctly, but sometimes throws the error "Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 200 with 400". I couldn't find a solution.

```golang
// router.go
reportRoute.POST("/query", func(c *gin.Context) {
        reporter.ReportInChan <- c
    }) // Unpublish report by id
```

```golang
//reporter
package reporter

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

var (
    ReportInChan = make(chan *gin.Context)
)

func Listener() {
    for {
        select {
        case req := <-ReportInChan:
            queryReports(req)
        }
    }
}

func queryReports(req *gin.Context) {
    type ReqQuery struct {
        QueryID    uint           `json:"query_id"`
        Parameters map[string]any `json:"parameters"`
    }
    type Req struct {
        ReportID uint       `json:"report_id"`
        Queries  []ReqQuery `json:"queries"`
    }

    var reqBody Req
    err := req.BindJSON(&reqBody)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("hata var")
        if ctx := req.Request.Context(); ctx.Done() == nil {
            req.JSON(400, gin.H{"error": "Veriler Yanlış Gönderiliyor. Lütfen Bilgi İşlem Birimiyle İletişime Geçin ", "data": nil})
        }
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot write a response after the handler returns. I don't see the part that does "return if request has not been closed yet". You need some sort of timeout logic for that

Comment: @BurakSerdar  if ctx := req.Request.Context(); ctx.Done() == nil {
            req.JSON(400, gin.H{"error": "Veriler Yanlış Gönderiliyor. Lütfen Bilgi İşlem Birimiyle İletişime Geçin ", "data": nil})
        }
section control the http is closed or not.

Comment: That part is inside the handler. The request cannot be closed at that point. The context for the request will be canceled when the handler returns. I do not see the part where the actual request handling is taking place.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I added all steps on the event-driven way. Still I can't see my fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This handler below will send the context to the channel, and then return. Once the handler returns, the request will be canceled. At this point, the receiving goroutine may not have had a chance of producing any output at all, but sometimes, it may. If the receiving goroutine starts producing output right at the point after the Gin framework writes the response but before it cancels the context, you'll get the mentioned error.

```
reportRoute.POST("/query", func(c *gin.Context) {
        reporter.ReportInChan <- c
})
```

What you really need to do is implement a timeout scheme, so if the request handler can respond before that timeout, you write it to the output and return. Otherwise, you let the request handler run, and find another way to return the results to the caller, maybe through another API call:

```
type reportRequest struct {
    ReportParams
    result chan ReportResult
}

reportRoute.POST("/query", func(c *gin.Context) {
        req:=reportRequest {
              ReportParams: {...},
              result: make(chan ReportResult),
        }
        reporter.ReportInChan <- req
        select {
           case time.After(100*time.Millisecond): 
               // Wait 100 msecs 
           case result<-req.result:
               // Write the result
        }
})
```

The above code will create a report request from the request context, create a return channel, and then send it to the report processor. If the report processor responds within 100 msecs, the results can be written. Otherwise, the results should be stored somewhere else that can be retrieved by another API.

The report processor should look like:

```
func (r Reporter) reportProcessor() {
   for request:=range r.ReportInChan {
       result:=processReport(request)
       select {
          case request.result <- result:
              // Wrote the result
          default:
               // Cannot write the result, handler returned
             storeResult(result)
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. Normally, I would have noticed the waiting part in the router section, but somehow I missed it. Thanks again.